# Timeout for file_get_contents for file in filesystem over Samba

Tags: php, file-get-contents, samba

I encountered an error trying to user file_get_contents like

```
$filepath = "sharedFolder/image.gif";
$contents = file_get_contents($filepath);
```

when using trying to grab a file in the filesystem which is shared over Samba.  Due to a problem with the VPN connection, file_get_contents couldn't find the shared file, and it hung up the entire script while it tried to find the file. Is there a way to add a timeout to file_get_contents that would be roughly equivalent to

```
$ctx = stream_context_create(array('http'=>
        array(
            'timeout' => 15,  //15 Seconds 
        )
    ));
$filepath = "sharedFolder/image.gif";
$contents = file_get_contents($filepath, false, $ctx);
```

but for a file on the filesystem shared over Samba rather than for http?

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion 1 :**

```
if (file_exists($filepath)) {
    $contents = file_get_contents($filepath);
} else {
    echo "Oupss VPN Error";
}
```

**Suggestion 2 :**

Make a symlink in your /var/www/html/ to your samba mount ... and use your code with stream_context_create .... (allow only localhost to access your new dir in /var/www/html)